# Parsing dates in R from strings with multiple formats

Tags: r, date

I have a tibble in R with about 2,000 rows. It was imported from Excel using read_excel. One of the fields is a date field: dob. It imported as a string, and has dates in three formats:

```
"YYYY-MM-DD"
"DD-MM-YYYY"
"XXXXX"  (ie, a five-digit Excel-style date)
```

Let's say I treat the column as a vector.

```
dob <- c("1969-02-02", "1986-05-02", "34486", "1995-09-05", "1983-06-05",
         "1981-02-01", "30621", "01-05-1986")
```

I can see that I probably need a solution that uses both parse_date_time and as.Date.

If I use parse_date_time:

```
dob_fixed <- parse_date_time(dob, c("ymd", "dmy"))
```

This fixes them all, except the five-digit one, which returns NA.

I can fix the five-digit one, by using as.integer and as.Date:

```
dob_fixed2 <- as.Date(as.integer(dob), origin = "1899-12-30")
```

Ideally I would run one and then the other, but because each returns NA on the strings that don't work I can't do that.

Any suggestions for doing all? I could simply change them in Excel and re-import, but I feel like that's cheating!

Comment: `Ideally I would run one and then the other, but because each returns NA`. You can use the `NA` as index to run the second i.e. `is.na(dob_fixed)` i.e. `i1 <- is.na(dob_fixed); dob_fixed[i1] <- as.Date(as.integer(dob[i1], origin = "1899-12-30")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We create a logical index after the first run based on the `NA` values and use that to index for the second run

```
i1 <- is.na(dob_fixed)
dob_fixed[i1] <- as.Date(as.integer(dob[i1]), origin = "1899-12-30")
```

Comment: This is great, thank you. It worked perfectly. Out of curiosity, is there a way to do this without creating a new vector (ie, i1)? Would that require an if statement?

Comment: @azul YOu can use `replace` i.e. `replace(dob_fixed, is.na(dob_fixed), as.Date(as.integer(dob[is.na(dob_fixed)]), origin = "1899-12-30"))`

Comment: Thanks, that's really helpful.